# MySQL Join multiple tables and sort by most popular

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have four tables, artist table, music table, music purchase table and album purchase table as shown below;

basically, i want to get most popular artist based on music purchases(purchases table) and album purchases (purchased_albums). any help here will be appreciated.

**artist**

```
id  name    
17  Rabadaba
23  Patrobas Abille 
24  Pryce
```

**music**

```
id  song_title  artist_id   album_id
30  Intro            17     15
38  Oli Mubi         17     15
52  Bwekiri          23     15
```

**purchases**(music purchase table)

```
id  music_id    member_id      
1   30                7       
2   38                7       
3   52                7
```

**purchased_albums**

```
id  album_id    member_id
1      15          7
```

**here is the database schema**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `albums` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` text NOT NULL,
  `artist_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `price` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `pic_location` text NOT NULL,
  `spinapp_cut` float NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=16 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `albums`
--

INSERT INTO `albums` (`id`, `name`, `artist_id`, `date`, `price`, `pic_location`, `spinapp_cut`) VALUES
(15, 'Musanvu Kitundu', 17, '2014-04-30 05:15:46', 12000, 'uploads/p18mor8nof4u9jmn1jarqem1t5o5.jpg/', 2000);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `artists` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` text NOT NULL,
  `date_posted` datetime NOT NULL,
  `pic_location` text NOT NULL,
  `website` text NOT NULL,
  `press_contact` text NOT NULL,
  `bio` text NOT NULL,
  `country` text NOT NULL,
  `artist_percentage` float NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=25 ;

INSERT INTO `artists` (`id`, `name`, `date_posted`, `pic_location`, `website`, `press_contact`, `bio`, `country`, `artist_percentage`) VALUES
(17, 'Rabadaba', '2014-04-30 05:10:09', 'uploads/p18moquhh918llbht17br1lbuig65.jpg/', '', '', 'Rabadaba, real names Ss real"', 'Uganda', 50),
(23, 'Patrobas Abille', '2014-05-05 08:14:04', 'uploads/p18n61g63h1imj1h7g1bmt2o7jr85.png/', '', '', 'About DUSTVILLE & CRANE GANG AMBASSADOR CALL ME THE DUST TRAFFICKER DA\n', 'Uganda', 40),
(24, 'Pryce', '2014-05-05 08:42:03', 'uploads/p18n631uoi10ogsrrp61mso196o5.jpg/', 'n/a', 'n/a', 'n/a', 'Uganda', 40);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `music` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `song_title` text NOT NULL,
  `file_size` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `artist_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `date_posted` datetime NOT NULL,
  `hashed_file_location` text NOT NULL,
  `in_featured` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `album_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=62 ;

INSERT INTO `music` (`id`, `song_title`, `file_size`, `artist_id`, `date_posted`, `hashed_file_location`, `in_featured`, `album_id`) VALUES
(27, 'Side Dish ft Cindy', 4896804, 17, '2014-04-30 06:02:21', 'uploads/p18motu3jt1s7k10r53rkasnqc65.mp3/', 0, 15),
(28, 'Yegwe ft Gatimo', 4544161, 17, '2014-04-30 06:03:16', 'uploads/p18motvqu9l09vu41n5h88huvp5.mp3/', 0, 15),
(29, 'Byanema ft Gatimo', 4477129, 17, '2014-04-30 06:04:08', 'uploads/p18mou1duo1nma1ealkdk571po85.mp3/', 0, 15),
(30, 'We Done ft Atlas da African', 4770033, 17, '2014-04-30 06:05:28', 'uploads/p18mou3oku1cv5ai8brgn4r87k5.mp3/', 0, 15),
(36, 'Okoona Mu', 3110008, 17, '2014-04-30 06:39:52', 'uploads/p18mp02v3v1a8pnatmj31jka1q6t5.mp3/', 0, 0),
(37, 'Tonsobola', 3879091, 17, '2014-04-30 06:40:51', 'uploads/p18mp04ck3kc861i7teidd1rj15.mp3/', 0, 0),
(38, 'Love Portion', 4486276, 17, '2014-04-30 06:41:31', 'uploads/p18mp05m1r116rrk11inbthroff5.mp3/', 1, 0),
(51, 'We Are', 4515443, 23, '2014-05-05 08:23:45', 'uploads/p18n620b5e1qr118ui1mcj1am0tmb5.mp3/', 0, 0),
(52, '256', 3679294, 23, '2014-05-05 08:37:46', 'uploads/p18n62pur24471h9o13hk115g11dm5.mp3/', 1, 0),


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `purchased_albums` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `album_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `member_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `ac` float NOT NULL,
  `sc` float NOT NULL,
  `paid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;

INSERT INTO `purchased_albums` (`id`, `album_id`, `member_id`, `date`, `ac`, `sc`, `paid`) VALUES
(1, 15, 7, '2014-05-05 15:52:17', 10000, 2000, 0);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `purchases` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `music_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `member_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `artist_cut` float NOT NULL,
  `spinapp_cut` float NOT NULL,
  `paid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;

INSERT INTO `purchases` (`id`, `music_id`, `member_id`, `date`, `artist_cut`, `spinapp_cut`, `paid`) VALUES
(1, 30, 7, '2014-04-30 06:20:42', 450, 450, 0),
(2, 38, 7, '2014-04-30 09:56:23', 450, 450, 0),
(3, 52, 7, '2014-05-05 09:17:34', 360, 540, 0);
```

Comment: you should put http://sqlfiddle.com/ link for such questions, so others can try it.

Comment: what you have tried so far ? show the query that you have and where you got stuck.

Comment: i was doing it with php. but wanted to do it with sql.

Comment: Post the tables and data in http://sqlfiddle.com and the expected result in the question.

Comment: dnt know how to use it... lemme check it out

Comment: I am missing `album` table

Comment: what is diff bet purchases and purchased_albums tables?

Comment: purchases is for music(singles) and the other for purchsed aalbums

Comment: @tarmaq i have aadded the album table to question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need another table `albums` that keeps just the following info :
id, artist_id, name

And then you can run the following query to obtain the information you've asked for :

```
   SELECT
x.id,
x.name,
x.date_posted,
x.pic_location,
x.website,
x.press_contact,
x.bio,
x.country,
x.artist_percentage,
SUM(x.sales) AS sales
FROM (
(
    SELECT
        a.*,
        COUNT(*) AS sales
    FROM
        purchases AS p
        LEFT JOIN music AS m ON p.music_id = m.id
        LEFT JOIN artists AS a ON m.artist_id = a.id
    GROUP BY a.id
    ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
) UNION (
    SELECT
        a.*,
        COUNT(*) AS sales
    FROM
        purchased_albums AS p
        LEFT JOIN albums AS ab ON p.album_id = ab.id
        LEFT JOIN artists AS a ON ab.artist_id = a.id
    GROUP BY m.album_id,a.id
    ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
)
) AS x
GROUP BY x.id
ORDER BY x.sales DESC
```

Comment: the other table is albums as shown in the database schema. when i run your query i get: Table 'c0relief_db.album' doesn't exist

Comment: ok edited your answer to fix albums but i get this error now. #1054 - Unknown column 'm.album_id' in 'group statement'

Comment: m.album_id should be removed from group by, just a.id

Answer (score 1):

This is complicated one, so here what you can try .

```
select 
a.id ,
a.name,
tot_music_count_in_album,
tot_music_count_in_music,
sum(tot_music_count_in_album+tot_music_count_in_music) as total_count
from artists a 
inner join 
( 
 select 
 count(*) as tot_music_count_in_album,
 m.artist_id 
 from 
 music m INNER join purchased_albums pa on pa.album_id = m.album_id 
 group by m.artist_id  
)t1 on t1.artist_id = a.id 
inner join 
( 
  select 
  count(*) as tot_music_count_in_music, 
  p.music_id,
  m.artist_id 
  from purchases p INNER join music m on m.id = p.music_id 
  group by m.artist_id 
)t2 on t2.artist_id = a.id 
group by a.id
order by total_count desc limit 1
;
```

`tot_music_count_in_album` is the total number of music associated with an album being sold as a complete album

`tot_music_count_in_music` is  the total number of music being sold as individual music purchase

You can take out `limit 1` if you want all the artist to list in descending order.